# decode textbox value in Base64 and break line after every string ends in php

Tags: php, base64

**i have a text box where i can paste the Base64 encoded strings Like that**

ZWxpZWVsYW1AeWFob28uY29t
ZWxpZXJvbWVyQGhvdG1haWwuY29t
ZWxsaXNjdXN0b21AZ21haWwuY29t
ZWxsYWxvMTAuZ3ZAZ21haWwuY29t
ZWxsZW5ib2x0OTFAb3V0bG9vay5jb20

and when i click the button Decode it should echo like the same way as i paste them in text box
Like that

elieelam@yahoo.come
lieromer@hotmail.com
elliscustom@gmail.com
elliscustom@gmail.com
elliscustom@gmail.com

**But i can't get that**

**i'm getting the result like that**

elieelam@yahoo.comelieromer@hotmail.comelliscustom@gmail.comellalo10.gv@gmail.comellenbolt91@outlook.com

Here is my code

```
<form action="" method="get">
         <textarea name="text" rows="5" cols="5" style="width: 400px;height: 200px;"></textarea>
         <input type="submit" name="btn">
      </form>
      <?php  
         if(isset($_GET['btn'])){
            $value=$_GET['text'];
                $content= base64_decode($value);
                echo $content;
         }
         ?>
```

Comment: If you input string doesn't have line ending ie. \n (*nix) or \r\n (windows), then output too won't have line endings

Comment: @viney but i have all the strings in base64

Comment: You're outputting in HTML also, so line breaks won't do anything, you need HTML breaks.

Comment: I see , as @miken pointed if you want line breaks in html run your results through `nl2br()` which would convert \n or \r\n to `<br>`.If you want to use in a non-web context it should have line break already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_GET['btn'])){
$value=$_GET['text'];
$ids = explode(PHP_EOL, $value);
$content = '';
for ($i=0;$i<count($ids);$i++){
    $content .= base64_decode($ids[$i]).'<br>';
}

echo $content;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid writing dangling `<br>` tags by using `implode()`.  Here is a functional one-liner solution:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/vn9R4))

```
$string = 'ZWxpZWVsYW1AeWFob28uY29t
ZWxpZXJvbWVyQGhvdG1haWwuY29t
ZWxsaXNjdXN0b21AZ21haWwuY29t
ZWxsYWxvMTAuZ3ZAZ21haWwuY29t
ZWxsZW5ib2x0OTFAb3V0bG9vay5jb20';

echo implode("<br>", array_map('base64_decode', explode(PHP_EOL, $string)));
```

Output:

```
elieelam@yahoo.com<br>
elieromer@hotmail.com<br>
elliscustom@gmail.com<br>
ellalo10.gv@gmail.com<br>
ellenbolt91@outlook.com
```